# Getting Started Template - Docker issues

Tags: docker

Anyone getting problems following the Getting Started template?
Tried 2 different installations and still getting errors.

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/101/developer-tools/walkthrough--using-the-getting-started-template.html

Some of the errors I am getting:

Error #1: `level=warning msg="The \"R\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.`
[image]

Error #2: `docker-compose : failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref  3f3de231-5630-4e0d-9880-af4d75348d87::bxasqp1metajlwinwtmzknhdf: "/C:\\module\\db": not found`
[image]

Comment: Could you attempt executing init.ps1 once more and check if you encounter the same error?

Answer (score 1):

Double check that you did a "switch to Windows containers" from the Docker Desktop system tray.  If you have the option to "Switch to Windows Containers" instead of "Switch to Linux containers" as a choice then this is probably the cause of at least Problem #2..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This looks very similar to what I faced after upgrading Docker Desktop and changing compose syntax to V2.

- Error#1 - You can search for an environment variable with "R" in it's
  value and remove escape characters.
- Error#2 - You can locate that volume in docker-compose file and add
  "\" at the end.

Make these 2 changes and try running up.ps1 again.

Here is a blog for reference - https://blogs.perficient.com/2023/07/03/migrating-docker-compose-from-v1-to-v2-code-details/

Answer (score 0):

These errors occur when complex string values are present in `.env` files which are not wrapped in string literals.

For example:

`SOME_VAR=BiMcQ.Rni:0w@\MstlSud>O+.StvvDm+vIvaBQb!3+-%@#;?Y5K|bJw@V9T[Lb63`

The solution is to wrap all of your complex values like so:

`SOME_VAR='BiMcQ.Rni:0w@\MstlSud>O+.StvvDm+vIvaBQb!3+-%@#;?Y5K|bJw@V9T[Lb63'`

Check out this [pull request](https://github.com/Sitecore/docker-examples/pull/63) for more info. I would encourage anyone reading this to submit similar PRs wherever you spot similar issues!